# Using Kotlin in a library module without using it in the app module

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to use Kotlin in a library module without using it in the app module. The app module only uses Java and does not use any Kotlin classes from the library. Gradle won't compile hoever:

```
Error:(2, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':<Library>'.
> Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.
```

Changes I made to include Kotlin:

{library root} / build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    ...
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

{library root} / {library module} / build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
...

dependencies{
    ...
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

When I add the same to the app module, the project compiles without issue, but I'd like to avoid adding it in the app module because I'd like to use this library in multiple apps without making code changes to those apps

Gradle version used : 3.3
android gradle plugin version: 2.3.3

Edit: @Jushua's answer works, but it still requires to update the project root build.gradle. I was hoping for a solution where only the dependency on the library would have to be added to make the whole thing work.

Comment: If this is so, export jar or aar file android use them. Otherwise you have to add kotlin support to app also.

Comment: If `{library root}` and `{project root}` is not the same, your `buildscript.dependencies` from library root doesn't applies to your project. You should add `ext.kotlin_version` and `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"` to your project root gradle file or you can import library as aar file.

Answer (score 8):

I am able to do that without any problem.

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.1.4"
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2", {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-annotations"
    })
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
    compile project(path: ":library")
}
```

**build.gradle (library)**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.library"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.1.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2", {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-annotations"
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

Comment: This strictly anwers the question, so I'll award you the points. What I was hoping to find though, is how to use a library in a project without changing anything in project except for the dependency on that library. With this answer, the Project gradle still has to be updated.

Comment: @NinovanHooff You have any change aside the library dependency, or you mean in the build.gradle (Project) file ?

Answer (score 5):

You just need to add in your module build:

```
buildscript {
  // (Optional) ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'

  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

and you could either declare the `kotlin_version` variable in that specific build, or declaring it in the project root build file, since the kotlin version could be updated from other modules:

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'

  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta3'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Worked fine for me with having :lib module and :app module

Answer (score -1):

You can add buildscript section with kotlin plugins only in your library:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"
```

And now you can include library to application, without modification of root build.gradle

```
compile project(path: ":library")
```

Comment: The answer is not complete. You need to add apply plugin: 'com.android.library' before the other dependencies.